# php variable doesnt echo when displaying in html

Tags: php, html, variables, echo

I am getting user input from a form where the user could enter double quotes,. However when i try to echo it in html it only displays everything before the double quotes, in the previous example it only displays 6.

I use a form with a drop down menu box and set the value for each option, here is the code:

```
<form action="component/content/article?id=11" method="POST">

<select name="categories">

<?php

$username="user";
$password="308715cr";
$database="test";

mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query="SELECT DISTINCT CATEGORY FROM inventory";
$result=mysql_query($query);


while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo ("<option value=\"$row[CATEGORY]\">$row[CATEGORY]</option>");

}

echo "</select>";

?>

<input type="submit" value"Search"/>

</form>
```

I use POST to retrieve the data. Then I display it as a  and thats where the problem is at. The page loads but the $category string gets cut off if there is a double quotes inside it.  For example < 6" Tropical Premium $8.99 > shows as < 6 >. Here is the code:

```
<?php

$category = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'categories');

?>

<h1>Category:<?php echo $category;?></h1>
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more code than this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Yet, from what I gather about the quotes in `6"` etc., that's where a (PHP) conflict may be happening as well as the `$` sign. Show your full code, or let someone else do the "guesswork".

Comment: stop using `<font>` it makes the Buddha cry

Comment: I would suggest first taking a look at the received HTML code. Is an empty page returned (this probably means some kind of syntax error), or does your code stops working between two statements?

Comment: most likely your html gets cut, you can try `htmlspecialchars()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use this with your `filter_input` function `FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS` .

```
$category = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'categories', FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS );
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

the info is little to go on but if you can try this:
< 6\" Tropical Premium $8.99>
if that works then you know your problem.... you need to escape your double quote

Comment: I put more info up, so I found where the problem is at, the string gets cut off after I retrieve it so its either when I set the value for my drop down menu box options or when I use post to retrieve the value. How do I escape double quotes? Thanks @lauw

Comment: its your value=\"$row[CATEGORY]\"  .... a quick solution would be to do this value=\'$row[CATEGORY]\' this would be my quick work around for now.

Comment: the reason for this is because you want to echo out html and html wont care about escaping it. so use the single quotes instead of double.

Comment: okay I got it. So value='$row[CATEGORY]\ worked, without escaping the quotes!!!!! Thanks @lauw